# Using modelOptions in ViewingApplication approach

Tags: typescript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm currently stuck at loading Models with a GlobalOffset. I've followed these steps: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/basic-application/

This is their implementation of the DocumentLoaded-event:

```
function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
    // We could still make use of Document.getSubItemsWithProperties()
    // However, when using a ViewingApplication, we have access to the **bubble** attribute,
    // which references the root node of a graph that wraps each object from the Manifest JSON.
    var viewables = viewerApp.bubble.search({'type':'geometry'});
    if (viewables.length === 0) {
        console.error('Document contains no viewables.');
        return;
    }
    // Choose any of the avialble viewables
    viewerApp.selectItem(viewables[0].data, onItemLoadSuccess, onItemLoadFail);
}
```

The last step in this event handler is calling `viewerApp.selectItem` ([see doc](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewingapplication/#selectitem-item-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback)). But this method hasn't a parameter `modelOptions` like the `loadModel` method of the Viewer3D ([see doc](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#loadmodel-url-options-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback)).

So now here's my problem:
I'm loading multiple models in my viewer instance and want to set the GlobalOffset for each model to `globalOffset: {x: 0, y:0, z:0}`. But i can't set the `modelOptions` for the first model which is loaded by `viewerApp.selectItem`. Is there any alternative to load a model using this approach?

Btw, this is my implementation (I'm using TypeScript):

```
private onDocumentLoaded(doc: Autodesk.Viewing.Document) {
    if (!this.viewerApp.bubble) return;
    var viewables = this.viewerApp.bubble.search(Autodesk.Viewing.BubbleNode.MODEL_NODE);
    if (viewables.length === 0) {
        console.error('Document contains no viewables.');
        return;
    }
    if (!!this.viewerApp.getCurrentViewer()) {
        var svfUrl = doc.getViewablePath(viewables[0].data);
        var modelOptions = {
            sharedPropertyDbPath: doc.getPropertyDbPath(),
            globalOffset: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
        };
        this.viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().loadModel(svfUrl, modelOptions, this.onItemLoadSuccess, this.onItemLoadFail);
    } else {
        this.viewerApp.setCurrentViewer(this.viewerApp.getViewer({}));
        this.viewerApp.selectItem(viewables[0].data, this.onItemLoadSuccess.bind(this), this.onItemLoadFail.bind(this));
    }
}
```

When my DocumentLoaded-event is called, I'm first checking if a viewer already has been instanced, if not call the `selectItem` method and load the first model. This is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. Don't know if it is the correct way, but it works for me:

I get a new Viewer3D instance by calling `var viewer = viewerApp.getViewer()`. Afterwards i start the viewer manually by calling `viewer.start(svfUrl, modelOptions, this.onItemLoadSuccess, this.onItemLoadFail)`

```
var svfUrl = doc.getViewablePath(viewables[0].data);
var modelOptions = {
  sharedPropertyDbPath: doc.getPropertyDbPath(),
  globalOffset: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
};

if (!!this.viewerApp.getCurrentViewer()) {
  this.viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().loadModel(svfUrl, modelOptions, this.onItemLoadSuccess, this.onItemLoadFail)
} else {
  // Get a new Viewer3D instance by calling viewerApp.getViewer() with an empty object {}
  var viewer = this.viewerApp.getViewer({})
  // Start the viewer manually by passing the url of the svf model and the desired model options
  viewer.start(svfUrl, modelOptions, this.onItemLoadSuccess, this.onItemLoadFail)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to use Viewer3D instead of the ViewerApplication:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized(){
            Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(urn, function(doc){
            ...
            var svfUrl = doc.getViewablePath(initGeom);        
            var modelOptions={
               globalOffsets: ...
            }
            viewer.start(svfUrl, modelOptions); // load your first model
});
});

...
viewer.loadModel(svfUrl, modelOpts) //second model
```

See [full sample](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/basic-viewer/#step-1-prepare-your-html) and doc [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#loadmodel-url-options-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!
This was my first approach. I implemented the viewer like your example above. The only thing is, that i want to add extensions to my viewer. As the [doc](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/toolbar-button/) says, it is recommended to use the ViewingApplication to work with extensions... Do you know if I can use your example with extensions?